# Use JavaScript to Parse Time

Tags: javascript, date, time

This is probably something easy, but I'm a bit confused how to do this.  How can I, using JavaScript, parse only the time from the following [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string:

```
 2009-12-06T17:10:00
```

In other words, with the string above, I'd like to output:

```
5:10 PM
```

Any guidance/tutorials on this would be great.

Comment: I didn't mean to close it as a duplicate of that question :'(

Comment: I disagree that this is an exact duplicate of the question shown. Parsing ISO timestamps is a different concern from parsing human input.

Answer (score 11):

Chrome & Firefox: Standard JavaScript Date constructor takes ISO 8601 date string. For example:

`var sampleDate = new Date("2010-03-07T02:13:46Z");`

Returns this Date object: "Sun Mar 07 2010 13:13:46 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)"

This does not work in IE (including latest IE 9)

Here is a cross-browser solution by Paul Sowden at http://delete.me.uk/2005/03/iso8601.html :

```
Date.prototype.setISO8601 = function (string) {
    var regexp = "([0-9]{4})(-([0-9]{2})(-([0-9]{2})" +
        "(T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:([0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]+))?)?" +
        "(Z|(([-+])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})))?)?)?)?";
    var d = string.match(new RegExp(regexp));

    var offset = 0;
    var date = new Date(d[1], 0, 1);

    if (d[3]) { date.setMonth(d[3] - 1); }
    if (d[5]) { date.setDate(d[5]); }
    if (d[7]) { date.setHours(d[7]); }
    if (d[8]) { date.setMinutes(d[8]); }
    if (d[10]) { date.setSeconds(d[10]); }
    if (d[12]) { date.setMilliseconds(Number("0." + d[12]) * 1000); }
    if (d[14]) {
        offset = (Number(d[16]) * 60) + Number(d[17]);
        offset *= ((d[15] == '-') ? 1 : -1);
    }

    offset -= date.getTimezoneOffset();
    time = (Number(date) + (offset * 60 * 1000));
    this.setTime(Number(time));
}
```

Usage:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setISO8601("2005-03-26T19:51:34Z");
```

If you do a lot of datetime manipulation in JavaScript, I can also suggest to check some JS libraries like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/). It handles some common things like date parsing, formatting and calculating difference between two dates and has support for multiple localizations.

Answer (score 0):

`string.slice(11,16)` will return `17:10`. From there (possibly using `slice` in more interesting and exciting manners) it should be fairly simple to get it into 24-hour format.

Answer (score 0):

This is so called ISO 8601 format. Mochikit comes with a function to parse it,

http://mochikit.com/doc/html/MochiKit/DateTime.html

You can get a Date object like this,

```
  timestamp = isoTimestamp("2009-12-06T17:10:00");
```

Just copy the function if you don't want use Mochikit.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the ISO timestamp is easy, formatting the time in a culturally appropriate way is hard (5:10 PM is not appropriate for all locales)  Many toolkits provide routines for the ISO part, and it's even part of the new ECMAScript 5 standard; only a couple do the latter part, however.

You can try [dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/date/stamp) and [dojo.date.locale.format](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/date/locale/format).

I believe Date-JS can format times also.