# Continuation of Count difference between two numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [this Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vQnHz/5/) which does not work in IE, but works in all other browsers can you take a look. What is the problem here?
Note: This is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117875/count-number-of-days-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

**Updated** : The problem is my example works in chrome but gives NaN in IE 8 and firefox 6.

My Code

```
var cellvalue="2011-08-18 11:49:01.0 IST";
var firstDate = new Date();
var secondDate = cellvalue.substring(0, cellvalue.length-4);
alert(diffOf2Dates(firstDate,secondDate));
function diffOf2Dates(todaysDate,configDate)
{
/*var udate="2011-08-18 11:49:01.0";
var configDate=new Date(udate);*/

var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = todaysDate; // Todays date
var secondDate = new Date(configDate);

var diffDays = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay));


return Math.ceil(diffDays);
}
```

**Note: My format**

```
2011-08-19 11:49:01.0 IST
```

Comment: Please copy the relevant code to the question and give details on the specific problem that you are encountering.

Comment: I think *you* should state the problem. We can only guess.

Comment: In Firefox this alerts `NaN`. What does IE do instead?

Comment: @a'r: I updated my question with my code

Comment: @pimvdb: Sorry for that, the problem is my example works in firefox and chrome but gives `NaN` in IE 8. What could be the solution?

Comment: @sth: in IE also it shows `NaN` only in chrome it shows result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the fomat of the date: ie doesnt support the way other browsers do.. run this: jsfiddle.net/vQnHz/7

it is recommended you use this constructor: var variable = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds2)

Comment: My format is fixed, I cannot change it unless after getting it into some variable is there a way I can put it in some accepted format?

Comment: Check with this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856199/use-javascript-to-parse-time